# Find a field extension F such that the entries of an eigenvector of a fixed matrix are in F

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

I was trying some old questions of comprehensive exams. And I have no idea of this one, could anyone give any hints? Thanks a lot.

Question: Consider the 3 by 3 matrix $A$ with entries in $\mathbb{Q}$.
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-2&1\\
1&2&-1\\
3&-1&-3
\end{bmatrix}
Describe a field extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ of minimal degree (either abstractly, or as a subfield of the complex numbers), such that $A$ has an eigenvector with entries in $F$.

My try: I calculated the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is $\lambda^3+\lambda^2-8\lambda+7$. And as I know, one of the three distinct roots is in $\mathbb{R}$, and the other two are a pair of conjugate complex numbers. And I was considering the eigenvector corresponding to the real eigenvalue, but I do not know what next step could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomial $\lambda^3+\lambda^2-8\lambda+7$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ (if not, then being cubic, it should have a root in $\Bbb Q$; but then the root must be in $\Bbb Z$, and an argument mod $2$ gives contradiction).

Thus the field you are looking for as an abstract field, is simply $F = \Bbb Q[X]/(X^3 + X^2 - 8X + 7)$.